# Why won't the application menu appear in Gnome Panel?

Tags: gnome, gnome-panel

In Gnome Fallback mode, the application launcher menu that is supposed to be in the top left corner is missing. Here's a picture: [image: Gnome Fallback Mode]

How do I get that menu to appear?

Comment: By the way, it's actually called Gnome Panel. "Gnome Fallback" is just a marketing thing to move focus away from the classic desktop and over to the new one, Gnome Shell.

Answer (score 1):

if you rightclick on the panel you can add the application menu. Here's the easy steps.

1. right click the panel
2. click on add
3. choose what you want, in this case choose menu bar or a custom menu bar for the **applications - places - system** links.

Comment: you need to hold the alt-key, or super+alt and then right click. To move applets, you press alt (or super+alt) and middle-click and drag.